# how to fix Datediff syntax in php

Tags: php, mysql

I calling out value from database where `Datediff` from `followupdate` and `NOW()`.

If the `followupdate` is happened before `NOW()`, it works, but if `followupdate` comes after `NOW()` it does't work.

This is my focus line. 
    `$re1 = mysqli_query($conn,"select booking.* from booking WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW(),followupdate  ) <= 3 ;");`

already try switch `NOW()` and `followupdate` back and forward.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");

$re1 = mysqli_query($conn,"select booking.* from booking WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW(),followupdate  ) <= 3 ;");
if(mysqli_num_rows($re1) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($re1) ){


     print "<tr style=\"\">      <td>".$row['booking_id']."</td>\n";
```

p/s: assumed the `followupdate` is always larger than `NOW()`

Give me a simple code that can describe what to do. thanks

Comment: _"won't work"_ means what exactly? There is also no `$date` in your code!?

Comment: sorry for that. i just edited.  wont work also mean if the followupdate happened after today it not call out. @Jeff

Comment: The big question is: **Which rows** are you looking for? What is the **expected result**? You have presented valid working code. No one is psychic and can look into your mind what you expect it should do instead.

Comment: the code is working if the `followupdate` is yesterday but it dont give what i want if the follow update is tomorrow. and and i figured out that answer is the `datediff` output was negative. and im using @Used_By_Already answer as solution. and it help me a lots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already tried swapping positions and still getting failures I suggest you use

```
WHERE ABS( DATEDIFF( followupdate, NOW() ) ) <= 3
```

so the date difference can be either positive or negative and your comparison will continue to operate.

Comment: I thought about something like that, however, it does not seem logical in real life. It is very uncommon to select rows where next update event is from day before yesterday untin day after tomorrow.

Comment: although it is not logical in real life, with this i also can know how many day in the date. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`DATEDIFF(date1, date2)` returns the result of `date1 - date2` in days. If `date2` is later, the result is negative.

`SELECT DATEDIFF( DATE('2019-12-1'), NOW());` returns 330 today, on 2019-1-5.

You propably want:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF( followupdate, NOW() ) <= 3
```